# modify a container in stopped state

Tags: docker, containers

I was modify the files inside the container. The container stopped working due to an error in file. Now I want to edit the file and start the container again. How this can be achieved please let me know.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Docker container is a file system indeed. `docker inspect -f '{{ .HostRootPath }}' [container]` to get your container's root path. And then edit the file as you wanna.

Comment: I tried - sudo docker inspect -f '{{ .HostRootPath }}' 0c01bb3137dd. The output was <no value>. Please correct me if I did it wrong.

Comment: Does the container show up if you do a `docker ps -a` ?